# Visual Studio 2017 Network Diagnostics Tool not applicable

Tags: visual-studio, networking, diagnostic-tools

I have a WPF project in Visual Studio Community 2017 and I would like to enable the Network diagnostics debugging tool but it is under the list "Not Applicable Tools" in the `Performance profiler...` menu, with the following provided reason: `Network tool does not support the selected target`. The selected target is `Startup Project`

Is there a way to make my project "applicable" without changing the selected target?

EDIT: I gave up on using the Network Diagnostics tool and ended up using [Telerik Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Answer (score 2):

[At some point in the past](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/network-usage?view=vs-2019), only UWP apps were supported by the Network profiling tool:

> The Visual Studio Network diagnostics tool collects data about network operations performed using the Windows.Web.Http API [...]
>
> The Network tool supports only UWP apps. Other platforms are not supported at this time.
>
> -- 11/03/2016

It seems unlikely that other platforms will be supported, since the network tool [relies on the fact that](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6f02cbd1-419c-4309-9535-137615b42aa2/network-diagnostics-tool#65a277f9-040f-4aee-9d45-5342c528095b) these projects make use of the "WinRT HttpClient APIs."

I can tell you that the tool was [introduced in VS 2015](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/introducing-visual-studios-network-tool/), and that I'm seeing the same result as you with my project (a console app) in VS2015 Professional.